# Rebasing with conflict in git

Tags: git

[Please I need help, I have been battling with rebasing conflict, the problem is after doing a git rebase origin/master, the rebase gave me an error which I resolved the conflict manually on my code editor by accepting incoming changes, I did a git rebase --continue, git commit --amend ], it showed me a vim editor which I resolved. Then type git push origin master and its giving me an error. What could be the problem here [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yx9EU.png)

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yx9EU.png): [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yx9EU.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Certain questions here are more likely to get helpful answers. Questions that share code as images instead of code blocks usually indicate you haven't read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), and people often skip right over them. So share your code as indicated. If you encounter a specific technical problem during that attempt, we can help with that, and we want to - that’s part of why we’re here. If you’re really ambitious, read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+Updates+were+rejected+because+a+pushed+branch+tip+is+behind+its+remote+counterpart

Answer (score 1):

To push to a remote with rewritten history you need to do `git push -f`
if you want more information about `git rebase` the git docs are useful.
the normal way of rebasing a conflict is:

`git add /path/to/conflicting/file`

`git rebase --continue`

check code

if the code works:
`git push -f`

else
fix code

Note: `push -f` will overwrite any different commits in the remote

Comment: oh thanks very much, I think what I missed to add was ,git add. before git rebase --continue. This was helpful